# Elasticsearch Python indexing operation to remote host doesn't work (connection refused) but cURL works fine

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a remote host that I'd like to write to with elasticsearch's python client. I have the elasticsearch service up and running on my remote host, and I have a connection/client set up:

```
conn = elasticsearch.Urllib3HttpConnection(host='https://my_host.net', port=9200, ssl_version='SSLv2')
es = Elasticsearch(connection=conn)
```

also, `curl my_host.net:9200` works just fine.
But running `es.index(whatever)` doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Elasticsearch host and port:

```
es_host = 'https://my_host.net:9200'
```

Connect to the Elasticsearch host:

```
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[es_host])
```

Hope this works in your case.